# Reference Token for Google Places API added Place is not working. Accepted Places do.

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have an android application that was working great but 2 days ago things started failing.  After debugging for a bit, I noticed that I was not able to retrieve details on places that I have added to Places API.  After doing a places search based on my location, I do see that my added locations are listed.  When I take the reference token provided and attempt to do a Places Details request, I get the following JSON back.

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

Interestingly, if I use the ORIGINAL token provided to do the same Details request, I do in fact get the details back as such..

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 44.2778780,
            "lng" : -88.39451800000002
         }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
      "id" : "c52c0ee9bdd0aea66419a0dfeaed32925f18216e",
      "name" : "Amc broom closet",
      "reference" :   "CmRgAAAAGZwx9penijotKZ9lizruTGr8KPbrTc4CD39tPQZ5rpsoEC0ofXDr
       2wpP0Ws9Vr1IIwGtTzRNyOYxOxMKQluhU-_SDydaPKJOsT9F2zqN8gBNPH-
       8Lenq4tkfLKdRmhF4EhD5KdxkNndh0J_cdy4lNPI
       MGhS8l2EdBcalDXfYRbkiFvWa3Bb8Og",
      "types" : [ "other" ]
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

If I then take that reference token and try to get Details however, I am once again left with ...

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

I am quite certain this is a new change..  Maybe I did not test thoroughly enough to begin with (quite possible).  It leaves me in a huge quandry however.  Because according to the documentation, my original token that works presently, might not work in the future!  I'm not sure how to program around that.

Please tell me this is a temporary blip in the system, otherwise, my paddle just washed downstream.

Comment: Is it possible this result is due to a using a debug key with Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, please post it [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Bug) so we can look into this ASAP.

Comment: Looks like it's already fixed with a commit coming this week.. You guys rock.